# Call a method contained in the class that is the hashmap value (Java)

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, call

**Library** Class:

**Old version** *printAllItems()* method can be used to call *printDetails()* method for each element stored in the ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<LibraryItem> itemList; // it declares an ArrayList of LibraryItem type 

----

public void printAllItems()
{
    System.out.println("Library Item\n");
    for (LibraryItem libraryItem : itemList)
    {
        libraryItem.printDetails();
    }
    System.out.println("\n==================");
    System.out.println("There are " + itemList.size() + " items");
}
```

> 

**New version** *printAllItems()* method can't be used to call *printDetails()* method for each element stored in the hashMap:

```
private Map<String, LibraryItem> itemMap; // it declares a HashMap of String and LibraryItem 

----

public void printAllItems()
{  
    // values() can't be used to call printDetails() for each element
    // it instead calls toString() method for each element, which is problematic for later
    System.out.println("Library Item\n-----------------");
    System.out.println(itemMap.values() + "\n");
    System.out.println("\n=================");
    System.out.println("There are " + itemMap.size() + " items");
}
```

> 

**LibraryItem** Class:

```
protected void printDetails() 
{
        String loan = checkLoan(onLoan);
        System.out.println(title + " with item code " + itemCode + " has been borrowed " + timesBorrowed + " times.");
        System.out.println("This item is at present " + loan + " loan and when new cost " + cost + " pence.");
        System.out.println();
}
```

How can I call the *printDetails()* in the **new version**?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve *exactly* because it seems you could just do `itemMap.values().forEach(LibraryItem::printDetails)` but I have the feeling it is not really what you want right?

Comment: I suggest you learn about `for` and `while` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're simply looking for...

```
for (LibraryItem libraryItem : itemMap.values()) {
    libraryItem.printDetails();
}
```

The `for (T varName : collection) {}` construct can be used to loop over any collection; `itemMap.values()` returns a collection. It's not an ArrayList, but that's fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the simple `Collection#forEach` method that will simply call `printDetails` on every object of `values()`

```java
itemMap.values().forEach(LibraryItem::printDetails)
```